# Test touch in wpf for desktop applications

Tags: wpf, simulator

I have created a build in wpf  for my desktop application. It have clickable and touchable buttons. How can I test the touch buttons? Is there any simulator/Emulator available?

Comment: Did you tried [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/03b6cd67-f0d2-4fb6-8d07-3ac799993383/how-do-i-emulate-touch-events-without-using-touch-screen-?forum=wpf)?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your OS version, you can do the following.

Windows 7 - You can create a custom TouchDevice by deriving from TouchDevice, see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ansont/2010/01/30/custom-touch-devices/).

Windows 8+ - Use the touch injection API.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802898(v=vs.85).aspx).